# Responsive and customize Timeline

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I developed a timeline, however I am having some issues that I can't solve :(

Firstly, the timeline is not responsive, ie when the screen enlarges or I put a larger description, the timeline lines separate and I always want to have it together, does anyone know what it is?

Second problem: Timeline starts at value 1, how can I always start at value 4?

As you can see in the image, I have both problems: separate timeline lines and it starting at 1 and not 4 :(

**HTML**

```
<ul class="timeline" id="timeline" *ngFor="let priority of Priorities; let  p = index;">
    <li class="li complete">
        <div class="timestamp">
            <span class="priorityNumber">{{priority.id}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="status">    
                <span class="circle"></span>
            <h4 class="timelineh4">{{priority.text}}</h4>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seen your code, If you are using angular then why are you doing it the javascript way.
And fixed as much I can in this [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbbqma). I cant understand your second question's requirement Please brief on it.

Comment: It is possible to change the color when the step is completed? At this moment they are all green, how can I make that being in 4 is green, if you click on 3 turns everything orange ...